# I designed a PCB around the IP5328P powerbank SoC and it is not working. Why?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, circuit-design, battery-charging, integrated-circuit

I am building a powerbank PCB based around [IP5328P](http://www.sztuofeng.com/upload/1586854246.pdf), a bi-directional PD3.0 and fast charge power bank SOC. I designed a PCB with components inspired by [NeoThai's work](https://oshwlab.com/neothai/ip5328p-18w-quick-charge-power-bank-module) on that and ordered the PCB. After soldering all the parts, the things happening are as follows;

1. When I plug in charging power through micro-USB and type-C ports, the LED animation of LED1, LED2, LED3 and LED4 shows that it is charging. The battery is getting the charging current, but the fast charging of the battery is not working compared to the original commercial circuit. The battery's voltage before charging was 3.7V.
2. When I plugged in the USB cable for charging my phone the USB type-A ports were not providing any power. Hence the output features are not working as well.
3. Push button works well. Single press, it shows the charge using LED bar display. Double press turns the bar display OFF

Here are the things I tried while troubleshooting:

1. I checked the circuit diagram with the typical application schematic (page 2 of the datasheet) and also another creator of a similar powerbank PCB on [PCBWay](https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/IP5328_power_bank.html) and the main components, but there seemed to be no faults by 3 more people in my acquaintances.
2. I resoldered a new PCB with the same components to make sure that all the solder connections were proper and checked each and every join thrice to make sure all the connections are solid.
3. Checked if the MOSFETs responsible for turning ON and OFF the USB type-A ports are working or not by providing an external HIGH signal to the MOSFET's GATE.  They turned ON but the voltage is not being boosted to 5V. Instead, I am getting RAW battery voltage on the OUTPUT.
4. The IC doesn't seem to be boosting the power. The original circuit already boosts the battery voltage to 5V at the drain of the MOSFET before turning the MOSFET ON. I can't measure that voltage on my circuit.

I'll be attaching the circuit diagram and the image of the PCB with this post.

Can anyone help me figure out the problem that I am facing?

[image: Circuit Diagram]

[image: PCB]

Comment: Please provide data sheet links for relevant chips.

Comment: May be the  IP5328P does the first charge ever only with slow small current to learn the capacity of the battery. Second or third charge of the 75 % discharged battery will be done with fast high current. The battery is a new one in good condition?

Comment: It's a brand new battery. A 10000mAh Li-Po

Comment: I already provided the link for datasheet in the description. Please click the hyperlinks

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is the VSYS net. In the circuit diagramm I see no connection from pad 8,9 to pad 22, 23, but this connection is required.